# Issue with linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic file during installations

Tags: kernel

Forgive me because I am a very excited, albeit brand new Linux user.  I started having issues with installs a couple of days ago.  I also cannot do any backups.  The errors I get all have to do with `linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic`.  I'm currently on `linux-image-5.0.0-21-generic`.

I get the following message when trying to run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which I think might be a clue to the problem:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firefox firefox-locale-en libmysqlclient20 patch
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/51.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,670 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 185702 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic (5.0.0-13.14) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-13-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: blinking: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.0.0-13-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated.  I love everything I've learned / tried in Linux compared to Windows so far, but this is a little discouraging.  Thank you in advance.

Here are the lines from grub:

```
blinking cursor# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=nouveau.modeset=0

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> /etc/default/grub: blinking: not found

erase in `/etc/default/grub`  `blinking cursor`.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but is this referring to the file grub within the default folder?  If so, the only line in the file with the word 'blinking' is the first, and it reads: blinking cursor# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update.  Should I delete that line?

Comment: It is best to see what the file contains. Use `cat /etc/default/grub` and post the lines into your question.

Comment: Yep. Then run the other 2 commands.

Comment: And no, don't delete the whole line, just the words `blinking cursor`.